# Is this a undefined behavior or not?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic

What will be the output of the following C program?

```cpp
main()
{
    char g[] = "geeksforgeeks";
    printf("%s", g + g[6] - g[8]);
}
```

1. `geeks`
2. `rgeeks`
3. `geeksforgeeks`
4. `forgeeks`

The answer is 1: `geeks`.

But I had an argument with someone that he said it is undefined behaviour. So is it undefined behaviour or not?

Comment: There's definitely a dupe somewhere, but pointer addition and subtraction aren't allowed to produce an out-of-bounds pointer even if you bring it back in bounds before dereferencing it.

Comment: (As some answers suggest, even if there was no issue with temporary pointers pointing outside the array) There is no guarantee that `'o'-'g'` yields a small(ish) positive value. On some implementation it can yield a large(ish) or negative value ... and therefore invoke UB.

Comment: @pmg can you elaborate a little on that..I didn't understand how 'o'-'g' can be a large value? won't it always be 8?

Comment: @VishalSharma I believe (some) current IBM mainframes still use [EBCDIC character set](http://ascii-table.com/ebcdic-table.php). On those computers `'o' - 'g'` yields 15. *On a Klingon computer with a C compiler implementation it might yield `-77` for example*. The C Standard allows letters `'a'` to `'z'` (or uppercase) to not be sequential, to have "holes"

Answer (score 1):

This statement involving pointer arithmetic is UB, because of the [associativity of `+` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

In this case (considering ASCII encoding)

- `g[6]` is `o`, which has a decimal value of 111
- `g[8]` is `g`, which has a decimal value of 103

So, finally the construct looks like

```
printf("%s", g + 'o' - 'g');
```

which is same as

```
printf("%s", (g + 111) - 103);
```

here, `g+111` points way past the array (note: arithmetic involving only one element past the array is valid), so this would be UB.

However, if we modify the statement like

```
printf("%s", g + (g[6] - g[8])); //enforcing precedence
```

which is same as

```
printf("%s", g + 8);
```

or

```
printf("%s", &(g[8]));
```

then it will be valid. However, if there's other encoding systems in use, and `(g[6] - g[8])` does not yield a value which is within the array bounds, it'll again be UB for the same reason as the original statement.

Comment: 'o' - 'g' is also not guaranteed to be 8. So I think the result is undefined even with the parentheses.

Comment: @VishalSharma I clearly mentioned the use of ASCII At the beginning, so this answer is based on that.

Comment: fair enough..but the question didn't mention it.

Comment: @VishalSharma Right, that's why I mentioned it in my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: On an implementation with a character encoding where `o` was represented by a value in the range 2 to 13, and `g` by a positive value less than `o`, there would be no Undefined Behavior even with the code as written.